# Pandas fill from last row meeting certain criteria?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a pandas dataframe which has sections looking like this (the zeros are NaN's):

```
...
     18  19  20
197  14  28  14
198  14   0  14
200   0   0   0
201   0   0   0
202  15  23  12
203  16   0  18
204   0   0   0
205   0   0   0

...
```

I need to fill rows that have NaN's on specific columns with values from the last row which has no NaN's on those columns.
In my example, rows 200,201 would be filled with values from row 197, and rows 204,205 from row 202.

LE: Rows 198&203 don't have NaN's on all columns I'm interested in, so they're left alone.

What would be a pythonic way of writing this?

Comment: Do you think  rows filled by `0` are replace by `198` row?

Comment: Why row 197 (second last row, last row with **no** zero values) for 200,201 but row 203 (last row, has one 0 value) for 204,205? Shouldn't it be 197 and 202, or 198 and 203? Otherwise the logic is not consistent.

Comment: Yes, there was a typo, you're right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need forward filling by `ffill` with [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) for create missing values for all rows with at least one `NaN` by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and then for filter out rows with not all missing values in row by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df = df.replace(0, np.nan)

m = df.isnull()
df1 = df.mask(m.any(axis=1)).ffill()
df2 = df.mask(m.all(axis=1), df1, axis=1)
print (df2)
       18    19    20
197  14.0  28.0  14.0
198  14.0   NaN  14.0
200  14.0  28.0  14.0
201  14.0  28.0  14.0
202  15.0  23.0  12.0
203  16.0   NaN  18.0
204  15.0  23.0  12.0
205  15.0  23.0  12.0
```